# Web3 transaction to a contract fails with revert. Same transaction works from truffle console

Tags: contract-development, web3js, truffle, revert-opcode

I have a simple contract transaction that creates another contract. This transaction when called from Node.js using `Web3` and `truffle-contract` throws a revert.

```
ContractFactory.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    return instance.createStore({from: accounts[0]}); 
});
```

Result:

```
2018-05-14T07:34:58.260Z develop:testrpc   Transaction: 0xc93859052bea36bd76c80ab21d30c90a3002303ec7eb1e3ea6d08cd002990d74
2018-05-14T07:34:58.261Z develop:testrpc   Gas usage: 89462
2018-05-14T07:34:58.261Z develop:testrpc   Block Number: 39
2018-05-14T07:34:58.261Z develop:testrpc   Block Time: Mon May 14 2018 13:04:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
2018-05-14T07:34:58.261Z develop:testrpc   Runtime Error: revert
```

When I call the same transaction from `truffle console` or `truffle develop` the transaction succeeds.

```
truffle (develop) > ContractFactory.deployed().then(function (instance) { return instance.createStore() });
```

Result:

```
2018-05-14T07:30:33.789Z develop:testrpc   Transaction: 0xbdc51bb74de2b59e98ad1b8f38ed4367c2d975a77340d778e44ee2ced969e5b9
2018-05-14T07:30:33.789Z develop:testrpc   Gas usage: 135843
2018-05-14T07:30:33.789Z develop:testrpc   Block Number: 38
2018-05-14T07:30:33.789Z develop:testrpc   Block Time: Mon May 14 2018 13:00:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
2018-05-14T07:30:33.789Z develop:testrpc
2018-05-14T07:30:33.791Z develop:testrpc eth_getTransactionReceipt
```

I've been trying to get `truffle debug` to work but it fails to debug transactions that create another contract.

My initial guess was that my Web3 transaction is running out of set gas limit, but would that throw a revert? I've tried setting gas limit to a very high value but with no better results.

```
ContractFactory.defaults({
  gasLimit: "100000000000000000"
});
```

Contract Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract SimpleStore {
    uint public value;
    function SimpleStore (uint num) public {
        value = num;
    }

    function setValue (uint num) public {
        value = num;
    }
}

contract ContractFactory {

    address public store;

    function ContractFactory () public {

    }

    function createStore () public {
        store = new SimpleStore(12);
    }
}
```

Note: Other transactions and calls work very well with the Web3 setup. This problem is common for all transactions that create a contract.

Comment: Did you try it in any other network that testrpc? try rinkeby and then post txhash for people to check.

Comment: can you post your NodeJS file?

Comment: I'll to make this transaction on a testnet and provide a hash today, I'll also post the Contract JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce issue that you were facing. I did following to solve this issue. 
Created two separate contract files inside contracts folder for SimpleStore and ContrctFactory as following :-
SimpleStore.sol file -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract SimpleStore {
    uint public value;
    function SimpleStore (uint num) public {
        value = num;
    }

    function setValue (uint num) public {
        value = num;
    }
}
```

ContractFactory.sol file -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract SimpleStore {
    uint public value;
    function SimpleStore (uint num) public {
        value = num;
    }

    function setValue (uint num) public {
        value = num;
    }
}
contract ContractFactory {

    address public store;

    function ContractFactory () public {

    }

    function createStore () public {
        store = new SimpleStore(12);
    }
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js file -

```
var SimpleStore = artifacts.require("./SimpleStore.sol");
var ContractFactory = artifacts.require("./ContractFactory.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStore,10, {gas: 6700000});
  deployer.deploy(ContractFactory,{gas: 6700000});
};
```

app.js file -

```
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
import SimpleStore_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/SimpleStore.json'
import ContractFactory_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/ContractFactory.json'

var SimpleStore = contract(SimpleStore_artifacts);
var ContractFactory = contract(ContractFactory_artifacts);
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source like Metamask")
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://localhost:8545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

  }
  SimpleStore.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  ContractFactory.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  ContractFactory.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    return instance.createStore({from: web3.eth.accounts[0],gas: 6700000}); 
    console.log("******");
  });
});
```

Adding gas cost as an argument has resolved problem of VM exception.

> instance.createStore({from: web3.eth.accounts[0],gas: 6700000});

I am also able to execute transaction from truffle console -

```
truffle(development)> ContractFactory.deployed().then(function (instance) { return instance.createStore({from: web3.eth.accounts[0],gas: 6700000});})
{ tx: '0x4d34e45cddbfa6f087f5dcb02bb5e7dc0fa18a0f7d24e87f8fff8702dd3e53bc',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x4d34e45cddbfa6f087f5dcb02bb5e7dc0fa18a0f7d24e87f8fff8702dd3e53bc',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0xf77b2baa3cacc941a8376376425c642c6db580e4a26918a0905ed589a618bfe7',
     blockNumber: 26,
     gasUsed: 123078,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 123078,
     contractAddress: null,
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be a really simple one: The `gas` amount truffle sends per default on a function call is 90000. You can see your transaction aborting at a consumption aborting close to that value. The transaction succeeds with a higher value though from the truffle console, which uses gas estimation, i think. What you raised was the `gasLimit`, which != `gas`.

So it's actually really simple (mirg's solution already has it, it's just not really terse)

```
ContractFactory.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    return instance.createStore({from: accounts[0], gas:150000}); 
});
```

Comment: This is it. I worked it out over the last weekend and failed to update here as I have been travelling. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Another answer came in before yours, but I had already awarded you the bounty, so I'm the other one as a valid answer to be fair. <grin>

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why will is not working with `truffle-contract` since there's not the entire code, but you can avoid using it and just create your instance using web3.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
    var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
        {
          "constant": true,
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "store",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "name": "",
              "type": "address"
            }
          ],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "view",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "inputs": [],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "constructor"
        },
        {
          "constant": false,
          "inputs": [],
          "name": "createStore",
          "outputs": [],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "function"
        }
      ]);
    myContract.deploy({
        data: '[bytecode]',
    })
    .send({
        from: accounts[0],
        gas: 1500000,
        gasPrice: '30000000000000'
    }, function(error, transactionHash){ console.log(error, transactionHash); })
    .on('error', console.log)
    .then(function(newContractInstance){
        console.log(newContractInstance.options.address);
        newContractInstance.methods.createStore().send({from: accounts[0], gas: "1500000"}).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
    });
});
```

just change this line `data: '[bytecode]'` with the bytecode and it will work.